# Bad Gateway 502: Add member to Teams using Graph beta Api

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-sdks, rest

The add member to Teams graph beta API works with some users while it gives me a 502 error with others.

Add member - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/team-post-members?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http

In either scenario, the call is exactly the same and the only thing that changes is the user ID
POST [https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/{id}/members](https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/teams/%7Bid%7D/members)
Content-type: application/json
Content-length: 26

{
"@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",

"roles": ["owner"],

"user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/{userID}"
}

Why would this be happening? Is there any way to solve this?

Comment: In the case where it is failing for few users, are those guest users?